# iOS 7 status bar issues with UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios

Yes, I have seen many questions about this, but nothing that deals with my specific problem.

I have managed to get the status bar to be a solid black (I'd like blue but I am happy that it is solid an not transparent).
I accomplished this by doing

1. in MyApp-Info.plist adding the 'View controller-based status bar appearance' = NO value
2. In the AppDelegate doing
   `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
      [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
      self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
   }`
3. in my `viewDidLoad` doing `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
   self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
   }`

Great.

[image]

But behind a UITabBarController it is still transparent. The view controllers inside my tabbarcontroller are subclasses of a the same view controller in the first screen shot. And the same `viewDidLoad` code is being called.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try to set the navigationBarStyle to default: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

Comment: Thanks, David... where should I do this? In the `viewDidLoad` or or in appDelegate?

Comment: I have done this in the viewWillAppear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of messing around I have a solution:

1) set `View controller-based status bar` appearance to `NO` in the MyApp-info.plist (add the key if you need it)

2) Put this in the master and detail view controllers `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [your background colour];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [color of the text of buttons];
```

3) This will make the top bar opaque, so, in the storyboard, if you have a uitabbarcontroller you need to set the `under opaque bars` setting on it.

As a bonus tip:
To make the navigation bar match it I do the following in the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc]init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[same color as barTintColor above]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the similar problem. To fix it, you don't have to disable `View controller-based status bar`

In `UITabBarController` class, set extended layout to `UIRectEdgeNone`

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Then set `navigationBar.barTintColor` some where else.

setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` in child view controller does not work.